# Can EOF be on the same line as \n

Tags: c, file-io, stdin, eof

As the title says can `EOF` be on the same line as `"\n"`? I am currently working on a project recreating `getline` in C and I am on the part of implementing what happens at `EOF` and I was trying to figure out will I get the last line of a text file as:

```
"blahblahblahblah\n\0"
```

or

```
"blahblahblah\n
 \0"
```

Comment: End-of-file, end-of-line and end-of-string are all quite different. Some text file formats do have, for example, `0x1A` at the end of the file as a marker, but `EOF` is usually not stored in the file. It is a value returned by functions reading the file.

Comment: `EOF` cannnot be stored in a string, because  `EOF` is a signed integer and does not fit in a `char`.

Comment: This is a strange question since the backspace you typed in your second example makes your example equivalent to `"blahblahblahblah\n\n\0"`. BTW I don't see why special characters like "\n" and "\0" should be written as characters in the text file, since they will not have their original roles as they will be interpreted as 2 characters each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can EOF be on the same line as \n

Yes, but rarely.

`EOF` is a constant usually used to signal 1) end-of-file or a 2) rare input error.  It is not usually encoded as a character in a text stream.

A return value of `EOF` from `fgetc()` and friends can occur at any time - even in the middle of a *line* due to an error.

---

Otherwise, no:

A end-of-file does not occur at the end of a *line* with a `'\n'`.  Typically the last line in a file that contains at least 1 character (and no `'\n') will also be a *line*.

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.  C11dr §7.21.2 2

Comment: @Malcolm Note that a `'\0'` read from a stream is not special.  It is treated as any other non-`'\n'` character in reading a _line_.  `'\0'` are not typically found in a _text stream_ but can exist - and cause woes for code that assumes their non-existence.

Answer (score 2):

EOF is a signal to notify that there is no more input. There is no actual data in the file called EOF at the end. EOF is not same of null character `\0`.

I think you want to know whether you can get an EOF without getting a newline first. The answer is yes. It is possible if there is no newline at the end of file, i.e. when the last line finished without a newline at end. You can generate such a file easily by opening a text editor, typing some text and save, quit without hitting ENTER. That file won't have any newline at end.

Comment: Some text file formats do have, for example, `0x1A` at the end of the file as a marker.

Comment: @WeatherVane but that's format specific. In general there is no such marker. And EOF is not guaranteed to be same of `0x1A`. I guess you have to handle such formats specially.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @taskinoor's and @chux's answers and after looking at your examples, I think you might be confusing `EOF` with the `'\0'`-terminating byte for strings.

`EOF` is a value that functions like `getc` return to tell the user that it was not able to read any more from the stream. That's why you often see this:

```
// fp is a FILE*, it may be stdin
// it may be a file on the disk or something
// else

int c;
while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    // doing something with the character
}
```

Note here that `c` is declare as `int`, because `EOF` is a `signed int` and that
is what `getc` returns. I previously made a statement here<sup>1</sup> that isn't that correct, chux
pointed out my mistake and I'd like to quote his/her comment here instead:

> User chux comment on my answer
>
> `EOF`, as a negative constant, is often -1 and can fit in a `char`, when char a `signed char`.
>   It is not so much that it does not fit, it is that storing a `EOF` in a char can be indistinguishable
>   from storing say a character with the value of 255 in a `char`.
>
> `'\0'` is on the other hand is the byte that is used to terminate a string in C. In
>   C a strings is nothing more than a sequence of characters that ends with that
>   byte. We use `char` arrays to store strings. So `EOF` and `\0` are different
>   things and have even different values.

---

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup>Note here that `c` is declare as `int`, because `EOF` is a `signed int` and
actually doesn't fit in a `char`, so it will never be part of a c-string.

Comment: `EOF`, as a negative constant,  is often -1 and can fit in a `char`, when `char` a `signed char`.  It is not so much that it does not fit, it is that storing a `EOF` in a `char` can be indistinguishable from storing say a character with the value of 255 in a `char`.

Comment: @chux thanks for the feedback, I corrected my answer.